# android studio 1.2 start failed with "java.lang.nullpointerException"

Tags: android, android-studio

i uninstalled android studio 1.0.0 completely and delete its' folders in my user folder ,then , install android studio 1.2.
now , when i start android studio , it gives me this error after loading splash screen and fetching android sdk component information.
[image]

**UPDATE:**

i find the answer , see this question.
[Android Studio v1.2.0 start up error : java.lang.NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30044635/android-studio-v1-2-0-start-up-error-java-lang-nullpointerexception)

Comment: By mistake did you delete the SDK also?

Comment: no , i download android studio 1.2 with sdk . sdk installed with android studio. @Lal

Comment: i delete sdk folder and error dont change ! it gives this error again !!