# Android Studio Start Failed

Tags: android-studio, startup, internals

I've just installed android studio. For the first time when I run that after a short while (after showing a loading bar), It shows me this error. So I searched in Internet and I did Everything I could,(downloading the last version on Java, re-installing the Program and run it for the first time as administrator, Adding the system variable `JAVA_HOME` and etc.)but still it shows me a dialog with this information:

```
Internal error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:178)
at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:52)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:362)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.AndroidVirtualDevice.<init>(AndroidVirtualDevice.java:81)
at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallComponentsPath.createComponentTree(InstallComponentsPath.java:89)
at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallComponentsPath.init(InstallComponentsPath.java:215)
at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.DynamicWizardPath.attachToWizard(DynamicWizardPath.java:97)
at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.DynamicWizard.addPath(DynamicWizard.java:233)
at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizard.init(FirstRunWizard.java:75)
at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizardHost.setupWizard(FirstRunWizardHost.java:100)
at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizardHost.getWelcomePanel(FirstRunWizardHost.java:92)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeFrame.<init>(WelcomeFrame.java:68)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeFrame.showNow(WelcomeFrame.java:173)
at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication$IdeStarter.main(IdeaApplication.java:302)
at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:172)
... 16 more
```

What should I do now only for running Android Studio?

Comment: I would suggest, what the error says: `Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues`

Comment: What operating system are you trying to run android studio on ? OS X, Linux, Windows ?

Comment: Whats your java version?

Comment: I use windows 7 @NialJG

Comment: My java version is 1.8.0 (version 8 update 48) @davidgiga1993

Comment: The address(https://code.google.com/p/android/issues) is just for reporting not getting answers.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30044635/android-studio-v1-2-0-start-up-error-java-lang-nullpointerexception maybe it helps?

Comment: Turn off internet and try starting

Comment: Hi have you solved this issue ? Please consider giving some feedback to the answers and their effort .

Answer (score 20):

Open the folder where you installed Android Studio:

> ex: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin

Find and edit `idea.properties`. You can edit this with use notepad++ or any similar application that allows text editing.

Add this line as the final in the file:

```
disable.android.first.run=true
```

Now run Android Studio again.

Comment: There is no disable.android.first.run in idea.properties

Answer (score 17):

**The Best and easy Solution for this is :**

1. Close Android Studio
2. Turn off Internet connection and be sure of it.
3. Start Android Studio. You will see a **popup box** with Cancel option in it.  Then Click **cancel**.

**Next Time you can Easily start Android studio even having an internet connection..**

Comment: Worked for me too!

Comment: I didn't get any popup, but disconnecting the internet did let AS start. Huh!

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. I just restart my computer as the it was not properly shut downed. Now its works. Hope this will be helpful info for others.

Comment: It sounds funny that restarting computer solves the issue. But it did solve the issue for me too lol thanks