# android studio start

Tags: android-studio

When I open Android Studio, a message displays:

> android studio start failed

I also tried to restart my PC and open Android Studio again, same result.

How do i solve this problem?

Comment: There can be many reasons, can you post a screenshot of the same.?

Comment: Maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/a/32766235/2308683 and other answers