# Android studio not starting even after laptop restarts

Tags: android

When I click on android studio this message prompts, I tried to restart my laptop but still this occurs, please help

```
Internal error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intellij.idea.MainImpl
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.lambda$start$0(PluginManager.java:81)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intellij.idea.MainImpl
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:224)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.lambda$start$0(PluginManager.java:74)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: What operating system are you trying to run android studio on ? OS X, Linux, Windows ?

Comment: i run on windows sir

Comment: Take a look at this question- https://stackoverflow.com/q/31264666/5265615

Comment: i tried them but still didn't come out successful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to see that but somehow your installation is corrupted. You have to [re-install](https://developer.android.com/studio/?gclid=CjwKCAiAl7PgBRBWEiwAzFhmml-7VU_26mDrWJXzsVlRJYBQXC54LqM3vHYHtykTyAjKHilZXI6vfBoCcY8QAvD_BwE). It will be better!

Comment: i did now sir, im gonna see the results. im updating later when I can run an app successfully too.

Comment: This type of problem maybe fixed by some hacks but it may create problems in future. so it would be better to re-install

Comment: I was done reinstalling sir and it turned out fine sir. thank you